# Append data to divs dynamically

Tags: jquery, dom, append, each

I'm creating eight divs which I want to be appended one and one to eight other divs, with the use of these divs classes:

```
var foo1 = "<span class='fooClass'>Foo text1</span>";
var foo2 = "<span class='fooClass'>Foo text2</span>";
var foo3 = "<span class='fooClass'>Foo text3</span>";
var foo4 = "<span class='fooClass'>Foo text4</span>";
var foo5 = "<span class='fooClass'>Foo text5</span>";
var foo6 = "<span class='fooClass'>Foo text6</span>";
var foo7 = "<span class='fooClass'>Foo text7</span>";
var foo8 = "<span class='fooClass'>Foo text8</span>";

$('.fooData').each(function(i) {
    $('this').append('foo' + i);
});
```

The .fooData divs (again, there are eight of them as well) is created before the divs that I want to append is created.

However this doesn't work (i.e no data is added to the .fooData-divs). What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** The .fooData-divs also have other classes if that matters, e.g:

```
<div class="color4 fooData leftSide"></div>
```

Comment: .Foodata doesnt exist, so that wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to use `array` instead of using variables and evaluating their names.

```
foo = [];
var foo[0] = $("<span class='fooClass'>Foo text1</span>");
var foo[1] = $("<span class='fooClass'>Foo text2</span>");

$('.fooData').each(function(i) {
    $(this).append(foo[i]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this. Worked like a charm! I'll accept your answer as soon as it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly everything in this script is wrong. The index of the `each` starts with `0`and you do not have a variable `foo0` defined. Adding to this you append a **string** to the fooData Elements, not your defined variables. Also `$('this')`(again a **string**) will not work.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, but what should I do to append the variables?

Comment: Do you want to append these 8 span elements to every fooData element? Or are the fooData numbered? Or what do you want to append exactly where? @Adil's answer shows you how to correctly use jQuery.each. Maybe this already fixes you problem? If not you have to clarify what you are trying to do.